# How can I pass parameter to a link generated by ActionLink() in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a route that I can access using the following pattern

```
ResponsesTotals/Show/1
ResponsesTotals/Show/2
.....
.....
ResponsesTotals/Show/n
```

From a different view, I need to list names and when the user clicks on them I want to direct them to the routes showing above.

Here is what I have tried

```
@model List<Proj.Model.Survey>

<ul>
    @foreach (var survey in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(survey.Name, "Show", "ResponsesTotals", new { SurveyId = survey.Id })</li>
    }
</ul>
```

But that for some reason is generating wrong URLs. Here is what is being generated

```
ResponsesTotals/Show?Length=15
```

How can I pass a parameter to the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `null` for the last parameter so you hit the correct method:

```
@Html.ActionLink(survey.Name, "Show", "ResponsesTotals", new { SurveyId = survey.Id },null)
```